# Bot Framework V4 MS teams channel and GDPR

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

Working on a Teams chatbot (V4/Node) and need to address GDPR.

In short, users of the chatbot need to be able to export or delete their personal data stored by the chatbot. Personal data is any information which is related to an identified or identifiable natural person. So also a user-ID in a state object.

I read a blog about [GDPR and bots](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/04/23/general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/) but this one does not address the Teams channel. And it is about V3

1. The personal data given by the user in dialogs (written by me) is
   the easy part. I will write some dialogs to show and delete them
   (like Bill does in his answer).
2. The content in the actual conversations is part of the Teams platform and will\should be adressed in Teams itself.

The bit I don't know how to address is the data for the bot to actually run (Bot state etc). What if a user needs to delete the fact that he or she participated in a certain conversation. That is probably stored in some state objects (in my case in Blob storage). But which ones?

I would appreciate some ideas\guidance in how to address this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not a GDPR expert but I believe the following to be sufficient.

From a bot standpoint the data stored is the same in Teams channel. You have the conversation state and user state data which is typically (and in most of the examples) set up using Blob storage. I use the `conversationState` and `userState` nomenclature for these items.

In my use case, I am storing account number in `userState` and user name/email in `conversationState`. Note that there are other things that the bot stores (particularly in `conversationState` I believe) around the state of the dialog and other bot specific things that are rather meaningless generally but I don't know if they would be considered part of GDPR. Regardless we will be wiping these entire objects out.

To do that, I created a dialog to manage the user profile which displays the key information stored (I'm specifically accessing account number, user name, and email) and then prompts the user for if they want to delete the information. It looks like this in nodejs.

```js
const { ConfirmPrompt, ComponentDialog, WaterfallDialog } = require('botbuilder-dialogs');
const { ActivityTypes } = require('botbuilder');

const WATERFALL_DIALOG = 'waterfallDialog';
const CONFIRM_PROMPT = 'confirmPrompt';

class manageProfileDialog extends ComponentDialog {
    constructor(dialogId, userDialogStateAccessor, userState, appInsightsClient, dialogState, conversationState) {
        super(dialogId);

        this.dialogs.add(new ConfirmPrompt(CONFIRM_PROMPT));
        this.dialogs.add(new WaterfallDialog(WATERFALL_DIALOG, [
            this.showInfoAndPrompt.bind(this),
            this.confirmDelete.bind(this)
        ]));

        this.initialDialogId = WATERFALL_DIALOG;

        // State accessors
        this.userDialogStateAccessor = userDialogStateAccessor;
        this.userState = userState;
        this.dialogState = dialogState;
        this.conversationState = conversationState;

        this.appInsightsClient = appInsightsClient;

    } // End constructor

    async showInfoAndPrompt(step) {
        this.appInsightsClient.trackEvent({name:'manageProfileDialog', properties:{instanceId:step._info.values.instanceId, channel: step.context.activity.channelId}});
        this.appInsightsClient.trackMetric({name: 'showInfoAndPrompt', value: 1});

        const userProfile = await this.userDialogStateAccessor.get(step.context, {});
        const conversationData = await this.dialogState.get(step.context, {});

        if (!userProfile.accountNumber & !conversationData.userEmail & !conversationData.userFullName & !conversationData.orderType) {
            this.appInsightsClient.trackEvent({name:'manageProfileDialogEnd', properties:{instanceId:step._info.values.instanceId, channel: step.context.activity.channelId}});
            this.appInsightsClient.trackMetric({name: 'confirmDelete', value: 1});

            await step.context.sendActivity(`I don't have any of your information stored.`);
            return await step.endDialog();
        } else {
            var storedData = '';
            if (userProfile.accountNumber) {
                storedData += `  \n**Account Number:** ${userProfile.accountNumber}`;
            }
            if (conversationData.userFullName) {
                storedData += `  \n**Name:** ${conversationData.userFullName}`;
            }
            if (conversationData.userEmail) {
                storedData += `  \n**Email:** ${conversationData.userEmail}`;
            }
            if (conversationData.orderType) {
                storedData += `  \n**Default order type:** ${conversationData.orderType}`;
            }
            await step.context.sendActivity(`Here is the informaiton I have stored: \n ${storedData} \n\n I will forget everything except your account number after the end of this conversation.`);
            await step.context.sendActivity({ type: ActivityTypes.Typing });
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, process.env.DIALOG_DELAY));
            return await step.prompt(CONFIRM_PROMPT, `I can clear your information if you don't want me to store it or if you want to reneter it. Would you like me to clear your information now?`,['Yes','No']);
        }
    }

    async confirmDelete(step) {
        this.appInsightsClient.trackEvent({name:'manageProfileDialogEnd', properties:{instanceId:step._info.values.instanceId, channel: step.context.activity.channelId}});
        if (step.result) {
            const userProfile = await this.userDialogStateAccessor.delete(step.context, {});
            const conversationData = await this.dialogState.delete(step.context, {});
            await step.context.sendActivity(`OK, I have cleared your information.`);
            return await step.endDialog();
        } else {
            await step.context.sendActivity(`OK, I won't clear your information. You can ask again at any time.`);
            this.appInsightsClient.trackMetric({name: 'confirmDelete', value: 1});
            return await step.endDialog();
        }
    }

}

module.exports.ManageProfileDialog = manageProfileDialog;
```

One thing I am uncertain of regarding GDPR is if you are storing transcripts or activity data elsewhere in the course of running the bot. For example, I am storing conversation transcripts in CosmosDB, which could include things like names and email addresses if they were provided during the course of the conversation. I don't have a good way to clear this information even if I wanted to. Also, I am storing LUIS traces and other information in Application Insights, which in many cases includes the activity which may have things like user name or ID attached. I'm not even sure it would be possible to delete those traces from Application Insights. I do not know if these fall under the realm of GDPR since they are operational, but if that is a potential concern just be careful about what you are storing in your logging and/or transcript applications.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I am not to concerned about data requested by the bot during dialogs. I know about that and should be able to manage that (like you do in your code)

I am concerned about data being stored in the background that I am not aware of. By the botservice, teams channel etcetera that would be considered personal data according to GDPR. For instance a persons Teams id.

Comment: Btw: what do you mean by: "Regardless we will be wiping these entire objects out."

Comment: I meant that `.delete` method is going to delete the entire context objects, not just the data I was explicitly saving to those objects. Bot State Service doesn't exist anymore, so everything that should be stored for use by the bot should be in those user and conversation state objects, though you might want someone from MS to confirm to be absolutely certain.

Comment: tnx. the empty object in userProfile = await this.userDialogStateAccessor.delete(step.context, {}) threw an error. I used             await this.userState.delete(stepContext.context) which actually deletes the whole state object (also from storage). Works for me.

Comment: Great. I'm not actually sure why the sample I first used assigned the empty object to a variable, but it works for me so I haven't changed it! There should be no difference in just awaiting the .delete action and not assigning it to a variable.

Comment: @Hessel if this solved your issue please consider accepting and upvoting this answer. Let me know if you have any other questions.